# In past tense which is right, 'I make them write' or 'I made them write?'

Tags: tense, past-tense

I want to know which is the correct past tense

> I make them write

or

> I made them write

Comment: Could you add some context and show us why you ask this.  What do  you think the answer is?  Why do you think that? What makes this question difficult for you? Why are you not certain of the answer?

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners, Ajay, and thanks for your question. This question has been flagged by the system because it's very short, and I'm here to review it and offer some suggestions for you. As you can see it's already got one downvote. You might be able to reverse this by improving your question. It's best to add as much detail about why you're asking the question as possible. Include what you already know and what you've done to answer your own question. I'll make some edits as a suggestion. You can accept or reject them.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is the second. Here is a bit more on the verb to make:

### **to make**

- **Present Tense:** make / makes
- **Past Tense:** made

---

- **Present Participle:** making
- **Past Participle:** made

**Examples**

---

> **Present Tense**
>
> - The boy ***makes*** chocolate cakes every month.
> - Anna ***makes*** cookies for her study groups.
> - The workers ***make*** tall buildings often.
>
> **Past Tense**
>
> - John ***made*** a necklace for Sherry.
> - Nicole ***made*** twenty copies of the document.
> - I ***made*** pizza for the first time yesterday.

Read More: [↗ Conjugation of To Make](http://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-english-verb-make.html)